# Technitium DNS service can't run

Tags: windows-10, dns, windows-services

I have version 3 of technitium on windows 10 64bit. but after selecting from menu of service -> start. Alarm appears:
can't start service 'DnsService' on computer ',', :

[image]

Comment: Anything in the Windows Event Logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill I didn't find any thing related on the windows events "Windows Logs"

Answer (score 0):

You got a very old version running. Try to install the latest version which at the moment is v10 and see if that fixes your issues.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1164802)